# ChunkLoadError / Unhandled Promise rejection Ionic 5 /angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, service-worker

I am trying to add offline functionality to my ionic 5 app. For that, I implemented a logic of storing information in sql lite while conected, and when offline bring data from sql lite instead of http request.

```
  obtenerVisitaDetalle(idVisita: number): Observable<any> {

if (this.networkService.getCurrentNetworkStatus() == ConnectionStatus.Offline) {
  return from(this.getLocalData(`Visita/${idVisita}`));
} else {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(environment.UrlBaseApi + `Visita/${idVisita}`, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    tap(res => {
      this.setLocalData(`Visita/${idVisita}`, res);
    })
  )
}
```

}

So far so good, but I came across the following problem:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/20859

Basically when I am offline, I am unable to open components like modal, since those have not been preloaded. Comment on link above mention using service worker to prefetch the chunks/assets you need ahead of time.

Any guidance, example on how to acomplish this, will be appreciated. Thanks

Edit: Based on first answer I am providing part of the routing file.

```
  {
path: 'pago',
canActivate: [UserAuthenticatedGuard],
loadChildren: () => import('./Pages/pago/pago.module').then( m => m.PagoPageModule)
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Preloading is supported from Angular Cli V6 so you might want to look into https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules. Basically you can preload all your modules by adding the following to your `RouterModule`.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
   routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules ,}
),
```

Or you can preload specific routes by defining a custom PreloadingStrategy.

```
export class CustomPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy { 
     preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {  
         return route.path == 'YOUR_PATH' ? load() : of(null); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, check Edit please. It seems like I was already doing It.